# gcc error no input files

Tags: linux, debian, gcc

Ive got server with Debian Lenny (32b) and I installed gcc on it. when I tried command 
`gcc --version` Ive got error "i686-linux-gnu-gcc-6:fatal error: no input files"
Can somebody help me where can be problem?

Comment: Does the command `/usr/bin/gcc --version` work correctly? `/usr/bin/gcc` is the default location of gcc.

Comment: nope, it gives me "no such file or directory"

Comment: `gcc-6 --version` also gives `fatal error: no input files` Whatever you did to install gcc-6 in Debian lenny didn't work because Debian lenny is an obsolete distribution. When I searched for a gcc package for Debian lenny I couldn't find one because lenny is obsolete. *All* your problems occurred because Debian lenny is obsolete. Update Debian or install a currently supported Debian release if you can.

Comment: I would like to, but I cant update OS in server which Im using

Comment: I 100% appreciate your dilemma and that's why I wrote "if you can" at the end of my first comment. My intention in writing that comment was to explain what is the cause of the problem, so that you can evaluate your alternatives.